# How to take any number of inputs through a loop if you are using an object that accepts a changing argument?

Tags: java, loops, parsing, object, arguments

This is for homework, so I don't want to post code or have someone do it for me. I'm an intro java student.

I created a Parser class that essentially verifies the format for an input. The assignment wants me to accept any number of inputs. I chose to do this with a do while loop. So at the beginning before the loop I declare my variables (including Parser parser; ). Then I proceed into my do while and ask the user for an expression, store it as a string called sentence, and then initialize the parser as parser = new Parse(sentence). At the end of the main method I ask the user if they would like to check another sentence to see if it's syntactically valid.

However when I iterate through a second time, obviously I can't initialize this as = new Parse because it's not new the second time around! But I can't initialize it before the do while loop because otherwise the sentence would be empty. The parser was given to me in pseudocode and I can't change how it functions.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The parser class was given to me in pseudocode. We are given a language grammar and have to verify if inputs exist in the language defined by the grammar. The object takes a sentence and then afterwards you call parse() which checks it. But I think I will change that and I don't really care if she takes off a couple points for deviating from the code.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score -1):

You have a few options here, and it will be up to you to figure out which is the best based on your assignment's requirements.

**Declare before the loop, assign within the loop.**
This is probably what your teacher wants you to do from the sounds of things.

```
Parser parser;
while (...) { //Your read logic
    parser = new Parser(sentence);
    parser.parse();
}
```

You basically setup a variable that will hold a reference to an instance of `Parser`. Each iteration of the loop, you create a new instance of `Parser` and *assign* a reference to it to your `parser` variable. Now, when you ***dereference*** the `parser` variable, it will lookup the instance for which it holds a reference. The `.` is the dereference operator in Java when used on an object.

**Initialize outside of the loop, and call a method within the loop.** In order to prevent creating objects on every iteration of the loop, you could initialize a single instance of the `Parser` outside of your loop. Then, you could simply feed your sentence to the `parse` method.

```
Parser parser = new Parser();

while (...) {
    parser.parse(sentence);
}
```

If your `Parser` class maintains state - in other words, assigns class member variables values during the `parse` method - then this probably isn't the best choice. While it would still work fine for the presented scenario, you could run into issues if you have a scenario where you need to do concurrent or asynchronous processing.

---

I imagine your assignment probably wants you to go the first route. Your teacher likely will want to store a result state from the parse on the `Parser` class. This data would then be referenced later.

Personally, I think that's wrong, and I think a lot of software engineers would agree. I'd probably have the parse method return a POJO (Plain-old Java Object) that represents the parsed result. If it is storing the parsed result as members of the object (thus `Parser` is also `ParsedObject`) in addition to parsing, then it could be thought of as violating the *Single Responsibility Principle*.